# onClickListener functions under OnBindViewHolder gives weird results

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm using RecyclerView.Adapter to display multiple ViewHolder carrying different messages. This is the onBindViewHolder function:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
  holder.submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        holder.messageTextView.setText("Updated message");
    }
  });
}
```

The weird thing that happening is that if I press submitButton on 1st ViewHolder, then the message is displayed on it as "Updated message" but then when I scroll down to other ViewHolders, the 5th ViewHolder contains "Updated message" as well and the 9th, 13th and so on already have the message displayed on them. Similarly if I press the submitButton on the 2nd ViewHolder, the message is displayed on 2nd, 6th, 10th, 14th and so on as well.

Ideally, it should work like, if I press the submitButton on the 1st ViewHolder, the message should only be displayed on the 1st ViewHolder and not others.

I had to put the parameter **ViewHolder holder** as **final** so that I can call it within the inner class of onClick function.

I have no idea why this is happening and I haven't ever used onBindViewHolder functions before but I feel it is something related to the argument ViewHolder holder being **"final"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the reuse of ViewHolder.
When scrolling the cells you are re-used and not create new ones.

The adapter creates a number of cells equal to the visible cells and when the screen scroll are always reused those.

You should save it somewhere such positions have updated the TextView, and add in onBindViewHolder a check to see if you need to set the text of the TextView to empty string, or "Updated message" based on the position

Comment: Got it! So I can just check if for some position, the button was clicked, then it will just display the message via onCreate of that ViewHolder. Didn't know about the reuse of ViewHolders. Thanks!